# ASP.Net Redirect Response to a IFrame

Tags: asp.net

How can I redirect the response to an IFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean from the server-side? - You can't!

**You'll have to do it on the client side.**

Say, use a javascript that sends an *AJAX request* and then embed your response information in the *AJAX response*. And have the javascript read the response and changes the page in the intended frame accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through a post-back.

Add a tag to your iframe like this:

< iframe runat="server" id="myIframe" />

in your server-side code (button click, link click, whatever posts back):

myIframe.attributes.add ("src", "webpage.aspx")

Answer (score 0):

. . . not totally sure what your trying to do, but you normally control the source of an iframe through javascript